# How to change border's color of any window?

Tags: winapi

In winapi, is it possible to change border's color, e.g. to red, of any window whose handler I have access to. If so, can you share some small example  (or necessary functions)?

Comment: No, borders are drawn with a system color.

Answer (score 2):

A window can take over control of its frame by handling the `WM_NCPAINT` message.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it depends! When Aero is running, then its no. When areo is running, the Desktop Window Manager (DWM) is taking care of handling the frames of running applications. When Aero is not running, then you can change the border's color of the frame of any running application by hooking the application and taking care of WM_NCPAINT and WM_PAINT. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540(v=vs.85).aspx for more details about DWM.

Comment: From an API perspective, is Aero gone after Windows 7? or is it still considered Aero - just not transparent? basically I want to know is it possible in Windows 8+ to change the border color?